# Cordova Ionic AdMob

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, admob

I am trying to implement AdMob to an app. I have installed `cordova-plugin-admob` and am trying to load `$cordovaAdMob` into controller as stated in official documentation [Cordova AdMob](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/adMob/), but I get unknown provider error. I figured that maybe it doesn't work in browser, but same happens if I run it on mobile.

If needed, here is controller code, but it's AdMob empty since I haven't passed even that first issue.

```
.controller('newsCtrl', ['$state', 'Injection', '$scope', '$http', 'SERVER', 'thumbSERVER', '$cordovaAdMob',
    function ($state, Injection, $scope, $http, SERVER, thumbSERVER, $cordovaAdMob) {

        Injection.ResourceFactory.getResource($http, SERVER, 'news')
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.news = response.data.news;
            }, function (error) {
            });

        $scope.thumbnailPath = thumbSERVER;
    }])
```

**EDIT:**

`cordova.js` is added automatically when creating new platform (I have installed android) and it is referenced in `index.html` by default. If I inject it, I get error

```
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngCordova' is not available!
```

Comment: Have you added ng-cordova to your project ? `<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>` in index.html and `angular.module('myApp', ['ngCordova'])` in app.js

Comment: There is a great tutorial here: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/wiki/Angular.js,-Ionic-apps

Comment: Mostly plugins don't work in browsers. Its better practice to check plugins in device.

Comment: I am doing it so, I get a blank screen

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up using the AdMob from [this link](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro), and following the "Quick start" section and conforming it to my needs, instead of "Installation" section which is obvieusly missing something